# 'java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA MessageDigest not available' when running Gradle tests in pipeline

Tags: java, gradle, mockito, byte-buddy

I've been getting odd errors in my pipeline when running Gradle tests. First it appeared as though Mockito combined with ByteBuddy caused the issue, but looking into it a bit more, the underlying error has to do with the SHA-1 algorithm not being available:

```
    java.lang.IllegalStateException: Could not initialize plugin: interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker (alternate: null)
        at app//org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader$1.invoke(PluginLoader.java:88)
        at app/jdk.proxy3/jdk.proxy3.$Proxy23.isTypeMockable(Unknown Source)
        at app//org.mockito.internal.util.MockUtil.typeMockabilityOf(MockUtil.java:33)
        at app//org.mockito.internal.util.MockCreationValidator.validateType(MockCreationValidator.java:22)
        at app//org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.validatedSettings(MockSettingsImpl.java:250)
        at app//org.mockito.internal.creation.MockSettingsImpl.build(MockSettingsImpl.java:232)
        at app//org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.mock(MockitoCore.java:94)
        at app//org.mockito.Mockito.mock(Mockito.java:1965)
        at app//{redacted}.my test method(MyTest.kt:1915)

        Caused by:
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to load interface org.mockito.plugins.MockMaker implementation declared in java.lang.CompoundEnumeration@6d303498
            at app//org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:58)
            at app//org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:69)
            at app//org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginLoader.loadPlugin(PluginLoader.java:54)
            at app//org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginRegistry.<init>(PluginRegistry.java:28)
            at app//org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.Plugins.<clinit>(Plugins.java:22)
            at app//org.mockito.internal.MockitoCore.<clinit>(MockitoCore.java:77)
            at app//org.mockito.Mockito.<clinit>(Mockito.java:1614)
            at app//org.mockito.kotlin.MockingKt.withSettings(Mocking.kt:166)
            at app//{redacted}.my test method(MyTest.kt:1915)

            Caused by:
            java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
                at java.base@17.0.3/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
                at java.base@17.0.3/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:77)
                at java.base@17.0.3/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
                at java.base@17.0.3/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:499)
                at java.base@17.0.3/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:480)
                at app//org.mockito.internal.configuration.plugins.PluginInitializer.loadImpl(PluginInitializer.java:53)
                ... 8 more

                Caused by:
                org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoInitializationException: 
                Could not initialize inline Byte Buddy mock maker.

                It appears as if your JDK does not supply a working agent attachment mechanism.
                Java               : 17
                JVM vendor name    : Eclipse Adoptium
                JVM vendor version : 17.0.3+7
                JVM name           : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM
                JVM version        : 17.0.3+7
                JVM info           : mixed mode, sharing
                OS name            : Linux
                OS version         : 5.4.109+
                    at app//org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:244)
                    at app//org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.<init>(InlineByteBuddyMockMaker.java:23)
                    ... 14 more

                    Caused by:
                    java.lang.InternalError: internal error: SHA-1 not available.
                        at java.base@17.0.3/sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.init(SecureRandom.java:114)
                        at java.base@17.0.3/sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:85)
                        at java.base@17.0.3/java.security.SecureRandom.getDefaultPRNG(SecureRandom.java:291)
                        at java.base@17.0.3/java.security.SecureRandom.<init>(SecureRandom.java:225)
                        at java.base@17.0.3/java.io.File$TempDirectory.<clinit>(File.java:1994)
                        at java.base@17.0.3/java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2151)
                        at java.base@17.0.3/java.io.File.createTempFile(File.java:2216)
                        at app//org.mockito.internal.creation.bytebuddy.InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.<clinit>(InlineDelegateByteBuddyMockMaker.java:123)
                        ... 15 more

                        Caused by:
                        java.security.NoSuchAlgorithmException: SHA MessageDigest not available
                            at java.base@17.0.3/sun.security.jca.GetInstance.getInstance(GetInstance.java:159)
                            at java.base@17.0.3/java.security.MessageDigest.getInstance(MessageDigest.java:185)
                            at java.base@17.0.3/sun.security.provider.SecureRandom.init(SecureRandom.java:112)
                            ... 22 more
```

I'm only getting this error in my Gitlab pipeline; it doesn't fail locally. My pipeline uses the following configuration:

```yaml
gradle:test:
  image: eclipse-temurin:17-jdk-alpine
  before_script:
    - sh -c 'apk update && apk add libx11'
  stage: validate
  allow_failure: false
  script: sh -c './gradlew clean test --info'
```

Locally, I'm using the following Java version:

```
openjdk 17.0.2 2022-01-18
OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 17.0.2+8-86)
OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM (build 17.0.2+8-86, mixed mode, sharing)
```

I cannot seem to find anything that relates to this question on the internet. To my knowledge, Java not knowing SHA-1 is a big problem.

Any suggestions on what might cause my issues are welcome.

Comment: Have you tried locally with Eclipse Temurin?

Comment: @kriegaex Yes, that works fine, which I find very odd.